# Excel extract distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: excel, distinct-values

I want to extract distinct values from multiple columns.
Example described below :

[image]

I have to columns A and B and the desired result is the distinct values between A and B

Comment: What about Pivot Tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use UNIQUE(FILTER()):

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:B,(A:A<>"")*(B:B<>"")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is located at `[B4:C16]` enter this `FormulaArray` in `[E4]` then copy to `[F4]` and `[E5:F16]`:

```
= IFERROR( INDEX( B$4:B$16,
 MATCH( 1, 1 +
 COUNTIFS( $E$3:$E3, $B$4:$B$16, $F$3:$F3, $C$4:$C$16 )
 + ( $B$4:$B$16  = "" ) + ( $C$4:$C$16 = "" ), 0 ) ), "" )
```

*`FormulaArray` is entered holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>  simultaneously, the formula would be wrapped within `{` and `}` if entered correctly.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2007, you can use the Advanced Filter

- Provide header columns for your data.

  - I used `Country` and `Year`
- Set up your criteria range:

```
A21:   Country
A22:   <>
B21:   Year
B22:   <>
```

- Select a cell in your Data range and choose `Advanced Filter` on the `Data` tab
- In the Advanced Filter dialog

  - Select Copy to  and enter a destination cell in the appropriate area.
  - Select Unique

[image]